# JavaScript getElementById(array).style.borderColor not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to change the color of a specific border of an object IN THE ARRAY, but I don't know why it won't change.

```
var x = [document.getElementById("SelectNro"), document.getElementById("SelectSubtype") ];     
document.getElementById(x[0]).style.borderColor="#FF0000";
```

Comment: Also, `borderColor = "red";`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is already an array of elements, so you just need to do

```
x[0].style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
```

---

> I don't know why it won't change

The argument to `getElementById` has to be a string. Any argument you pass to it will be converted to a string *implicitly*. Converting a DOM element to a string results in something like `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`, i.e. `document.getElementById(x[0])` would look for an element with ID `[object HTMLDivElement]` (which most likely doesn't exist).